# Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$image

Tags: laravel, pagination

I need your help with this `simplePaginate();`
controller:

```
foreach($lesson->products as $product)
{
    $p[] = $product->simplePaginate(1);
}
```

view:

```
            @foreach($p as $data)
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$data->image) }}" alt="">
            @endforeach

        {{ $p->links('layouts.paginate') }}
```

what is wrong that I got this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$image
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here... You'd need another foreach, like `foreach($p as $paginator)`, then `foreach($paginator as $data)`, then `$data->image` should work... But... Still not sure why you're doing this...

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you remove that foreach to generate `$p` and loop `$lesson->products` in the blade directly

```
@foreach($lesson->products as $product)
    <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$product->image) }}" alt="">
@endforeach
```

If you need the simplePaginate() for reasons not posted in your question, then you can loop it like this

```
@foreach($p as $productSimplePaginate)
    @foreach($productSimplePaginate as $product)
        <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$product->image) }}" alt="">
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I know that but as you see I need simple paginate and So I used foreach in controller

Comment: @mary why do you need to simple paginate with a limit 1 when the product instance  is already there. it is equivalent to `first()` with encapsulation an will return the same product in each loop.

Comment: @mary added another example, with the variable names to explain what it contains, to the answer